# Incompatibility between Python 3.2 and Qt?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, compatibility

I have problems with Python 3.2 and PyQt 4.8.6
It seems as if Python 3.2 can`t find the imports.
Especially the "Q"-methods. For example the QString below.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s
```

With Python 2.7 everything works fine.
Where is the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python3 made many incompatible changes in order to "clean up" the language, and, to a certain extent, PyQt has done the same by introducing "more pythonic" versions of some APIs. But these different API versions can be selected on a class by class basis for both Python2 *and* Python3, so the only real difference is the defaults chosen for each Python version.

In Python2, the default API version for `QString` is "v1", which implements it as a Python type; in Python3 the default is "v2", which automatically converts to and from the appropriate Python string object.

The API version can be selected by using the `setapi` function from the `sip` package. So to continue using the `QString` class in your application, just make sure the appropropriate version is set before the PyQt modules are first imported:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 1)

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s
```

For details of all the APIs that can be set this way, see [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/incompatible_apis.html#ref-incompat-apis).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [notes about Python 3 in the PyQt Reference Guide](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/python_v3.html).

> The QString class is implemented as a mapped type that is
>   automatically converted to and from a Python string. In addition a
>   None is converted to a null QString. However, a null QString is
>   converted to an empty Python string (and not None). (This is because
>   Qt often returns a null QString when it should probably return an
>   empty QString.)

I've not moved any code over to Python 3 yet, but I believe that the idea is to use normal Python strings instead of QStrings. PyQt will accept them and they already support unicode in Python 3. Where normally a PyQt function would return a QString it will return a regular python string under Python 3.

Have a look at the other differences on the linked page too.