# PyQt4 - QString object has no attribute 'isEmpty''

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt4, qstring

I'm trying to use a PyQt file on Python 3.4, that was originally targeted for Python 2.7. I don't have 2.7 installed, but I trust the code originally worked.

The error I'm seeing is on the `strVal` returned from `QInputDialog.getItem`:

```
import  random, sys, queue, serial, glob, os, csv, time
import  PyQt4.Qwt5     as Qwt
from    PyQt4.QtCore   import *  
from    PyQt4.QtGui    import *

...

strVal , ok = QInputDialog.getItem(self, 'Select a port',
    'Serial port:', ports, 0, False)

if ok and not strVal.isEmpty():
    self.portname.setText(strVal)
```

From the documentation, `QInputDialog.getItem` should return a `QString` (not just a string), and `QString` objects have the attribute `.isEmpty()`.

Since I get the no `.isEmpty()` attribute, is it somehow not importing `QString`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incompatibility between Python 3.2 and Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307985/incompatibility-between-python-3-2-and-qt)

Answer (score 1):

The return type is a regular python string, not QString, since the implementation of "API #2" in pyqt4 (also for pyside). Since an empty string is considered falsy, you can do

```
 if ok and strVal:
      self.portname.setText(strVal)
```

Comment: Additional info about API #1, API #2 and PySide: http://spyder-ide.blogspot.com/2011/06/pyqt-api-1-pyqt-api-2-and-pyside.html